# Problema con comillas al pasar argumento en una función dentro de un onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo esta variable en `javascript`

```
var ACTIONS =
    "<div class='btn-group' role='group'>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='/users/show/edit/" + row.id + "'>Edit</a>"+
        "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-success' href='/users/show/read/" + row.id + "'>Show</a>"+
        "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' onclick='destroyUser('" + row.name + "');' >Delete</a>"+  // <-- Mi problema es aquí
    "</div>";
```

Cuando el documento termina de cargar al inspeccionar el elemento me lo muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería mostrarmelo así: `onclick="destroyUser('jhon doe');"`

¿Cómo puedo corregir esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes reemplazar las comillas actuales por dobles en el valor del atributo y hacer el "escape" respectivo de dichas comillas:

```js
var row = {id:1, name:'John'};

var actions =
    "<div class='btn-group' role='group'>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='/users/show/edit/" + row.id + "'>Edit</a>"+
        "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-success' href='/users/show/read/" + row.id + "'>Show</a>"+
        "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' onclick=\"destroyUser('" + row.name + "');\" >Delete</a>"+
    "</div>";

document.write(actions);
```

Comment: Consideraré tu respuesta como correcta gracias a que me diste la idea de hacer el "escape" a las comillas, luego de un rato intentando resultó funcionando de esta forma: `'<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="destroyUser(\'' + row.name + '\', ' + row.id + ');" >Delete</a>'`, al inspeccionar el elemento ya me lo mostraba correctamente `destroyUser('Jhon Doe', 1);`